# A strange case of applying the Leibniz integral rule

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, leibniz-integral-rule

While trying to prove something, I came up with a strange case involving the use of Leibniz integral rule.

Let a variable $x$ be parametrized by $t$ so that $x=x(t)$.
Now I want to take the derivative with respect to $x(t)$ an integral:
$$\frac{d}{dx(t)}\int_0^tf(x(t'))dt'$$  for a well-behaved function $f(x(t))$ and with $\frac{d}{dx(t)}$ representing just the normal derivative wrt $x(t)$.
The problem is that I don't know how to actually apply the Leibniz rule to the above operator.
Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Also, how does it generalize when $x(t)\rightarrow\vec{x(t)}=(x(t), y(t), z(t))$ and $\frac{d}{dx(t)}\rightarrow\nabla$?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Yeah, I thought it might be more appropriate there, but over there they might get hung up on some details that physicists don't get hung up with due to them being more rigorous in their treatment of mathematics at most of the times.

Comment: Are you familiar with $dx=\dot{x}~ dt$?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes. So, should I write $\frac{d}{dt}=\frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dt}}\frac{d}{dt}$? If so, is there a "nice" way to write this for the generalization of the above to the 3D case?

Comment: The easiest is to do a first-order expansion and then read the derivative:

$$\int_0^t f(x(t')+\delta x(t'))dt' = \int_0^t \left[f(x(t'))+\frac{df}{dx}(x(t'))\delta x(t')+\cdots \right] dt'$$
You can then nicely generalise that to the case where $x$ is actually a vector.

Comment: Yes; yes.    A gradient is an array of 3 separate components.

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis Would you care to write an answer for that? I am not really all that well-acquainted with what you are suggesting.

Comment: @CosmasZachos That would give an "ugly" result though. Except if there is a nice way to tidy it all up. In any way, I will try this and proceed. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hmmm...not sure if this really falls int Leibnitz as $f(x,t)$ and $f(x(t))$ is quite a difference. Anyway I would start by saying everything is well behaved so if I have x(t), I have t(x) giving me $\frac{d}{d x}\int_0^{t(x)} dt' f(x(t'))$, which look sort of more Leibniz-ish? But then would $f(x(t'))$ not just be some $g(t')$?

Comment: @mikuszefski I think it falls into Leibniz integral rule category since the derivative must also "hit" the upper boundary of the integral.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x} \int_0^t \mathrm{d}t' f(x(t'))&=&\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d} t}\int_0^t \mathrm{d}t' f(x(t'))\\
&=&\frac{1}{ \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\int_0^t \mathrm{d}t' g(t')\\
&=&\frac{1}{ \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}} g(t)\\
&=&\frac{1}{ \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}} f(x(t))
\end{align}
$$